# With ES6 Classes, is it ok to return an instantiation of that class from a static method?

Tags: javascript, class, static, ecmascript-6, es6-class

```
class Thing {
  constructor(parameter) {
    if (parameter) {
      this.x = parameter;
    }
    return this;
  }

  getX () {
    return this.x;
  }

  static specialThing() {
    return new Thing('Special Thing');
  }
}

let thingy = Thing.specialThing();
thingy.getX(); // 'Special Thing'
```

I'd like to do the above in JavaScript (albeit in a more complex form). It runs fine currently when I run this code, but I feel odd about having a function within a class return an instantiated version of that class. Is there any reason not to build my code this way?

A functioning alternative to a static method is:

```
Thing.specialThing = () => {
  return new Thing('Special Thing');
};
```

What are some pluses and minuses (if any) to using either one of these things? Are there any other better ways to accomplish this goal that I'm not aware of?

Comment: There's nothing at all wrong with that.

Comment: this structure is extremely common in other languages, the only reason you probably havent seen it in js is because classes are new to javascript..

Comment: Cool thanks for the responses @Pointy & @Pamblam! 

Also general question - why comment with an answer instead of answering?

Comment: Well I can't speak for anybody else but if it's just a matter of opinion kind of thing, and I don't consider myself an expert, I'll drop a comment. I couldn't provide a thorough explanation and defense of *why* it's an OK practice, in other words.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks for enlightening me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> With ES6 Classes, is it ok to return an instantiation of that class
>   from a static method?

Sure, that's fine and it is an accepted practice for some circumstances.  It would typically be used when you want to codify into a reusable function that can be called from several places a specific way of calling a constructor and creating an object.

Your static function named `specialThing` is called a factory function (a regular function that creates and returns an object for you).  A factory function can be either a static method like you show, a method of some other type of object or just a regular function (basically any type of function, static or not).

So, imagine you had four places in your code that all created the same type of object with the same or mostly the same arguments to a constructor.  Rather than copy that code into four places, you just create a shared function that does all the common work for you and you can then use that in multiple places just like you would do for putting any other common code into a shared function.  Except when you're creating and returning an object, that type of shared function has a particular name (a factory function).  As I said earlier, the factory function can be any kind of function (whatever is most appropriate for your coding design) so a static method is certainly one of the acceptable ways of coding it.

Answer (score 1):

> With ES6 Classes, is it ok to return an instantiation of that class from a static method?

Yep, really common in functional programming too

```js
class Box {
  constructor (value) {
    this.value = value
  }
  fmap (f) {
    return Box.of (f (this.value))
  }
  concat ({value}) {
    return Box.of (this.value + value)
  }
  static of (value) {
    return new Box (value)
  }
}

const sq = x => x * x

let b = Box.of(3).fmap(sq).concat(Box.of(4).fmap(sq))

console.log (b)
// { Box 3*3 + 4*4 }
// { Box 25 }
```